# How could I edit the crontab jobs from PHP without damaging the file?

Tags: bash, apache, cron, raspberry-pi

It turns out that I have a platform in Raspberry, the idea is that from there you can edit the tasks of the crontab and the USB Kernels, this I am doing it in the following way:

- I visualize the crontab and the Kernels from the web.
  [Image of web page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c5KG.png)
- With some buttons to edit I go to another page with the text of what is inside the Crontab or the Kernel, there I create a text file with what I just edited. [After press the edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLDjN.png)

I create the file like this...

```
<?php
function Write() {
   $edit_file = $_POST["type_file"];
   $data = $_POST["tekst"];
   #file_put_contents($edit_file, $data);
   if ($_POST["number_file"] == "1") {
        $nombre_archivo = "crontab_backup";
        $file = fopen($nombre_archivo, "w");
        fwrite($file, $data);
        fclose($file);
        header('Refresh: 2; url=index.php');
        #echo $data;
   }elseif ($_POST["number_file"] == "2") {
        $nombre_archivo = "999_usbdevices.rules";
        $file = fopen($nombre_archivo, "w");
        fwrite($file, $data);
        fclose($file);
        header('Refresh: 2; url=index.php');
        #echo $data;
   }
   header('Refresh: 2; url=index.php');
}
?>
```

- In the Raspberry I have a code that verifies when this file has been edited and with the command 'sudo crontab -u pi / var / www / html / SIATA / crontab_backup' I send it to the crontab.

This is the code:

```
backup1=$(sudo cp /etc/udev/rules.d/999_usbdevices.rules /tmp/999_usbdevices.txt)
backup2=$(crontab -u pi -l> /tmp/crontab_backup.txt)

shell=$(stat -c%y /var/www/html/SIATA/crontab_backup)
ult_mod=$(stat -c%y /var/www/html/SIATA/crontab_backup)

shellUSB=$(stat -c%y /var/www/html/SIATA/999_usbdevices.rules)
ult_modUSB=$(stat -c%y /var/www/html/SIATA/999_usbdevices.rules)

while [ true ]; do
    actual=$(stat -c%y /var/www/html/SIATA/crontab_backup)
    actualUSB=$(stat -c%y /var/www/html/SIATA/999_usbdevices.rules)

       if [ "$ult_mod" != "$actual" ]
           then
               ult_mod=$(stat -c%y /var/www/html/SIATA/crontab_backup)
               shell=$(sudo crontab -u pi /var/www/html/SIATA/crontab_backup)
               delete=$(sudo rm /tmp/crontab_backup.txt)
               shell2=$(crontab -u pi -l> /tmp/crontab_backup.txt)
               echo $shell
               echo $shell2
       fi

       if [ "$ult_modUSB" != "$actualUSB" ]
           then
               ult_modUSB=$(stat -c%y /var/www/html/SIATA/999_usbdevices.rules)
               shellUSB=$(sudo cp /var/www/html/SIATA/999_usbdevices.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/999_usbdevices.rules)
               delete=$(sudo rm /tmp/999_usbdevices.txt)
               shell2USB=$(sudo cp /etc/udev/rules.d/999_usbdevices.rules '/tmp/999_usbdevices.txt')
               echo $shellUSB
               echo $shell2USB
       fi
   backup1=$(sudo cp /etc/udev/rules.d/999_usbdevices.rules /tmp/999_usbdevices.txt)
   backup2=$(crontab -u pi -l> /tmp/crontab_backup.txt)
done
```

Everything it do very well, but the moment he edits the crontab, it becomes unusable, it no longer performs the tasks that are inside...

Can somebody help me??

Regards.

Comment: Please include your code not just a picture of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve the problem, it was necessary to format the file before importing it into crontab, this I did with dos2unix and it immediately worked.

```
sudo apt-get install tofrodos
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/fromdos /usr/bin/dos2unix
dos2unix /var/www/html/crontab_backup
```

I hope it serves someone. Regards.